# Displaying layer after using QgsGeometryAnalyser?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have already discovered this class, but I am confused. If I am doing a analysis on the current layer, I don't know why it is not displaying on the map.

```
lyr =iface.mapCanvas()
layer = lyr.currentLayer()
QgsGeometryAnalyzer().centroids(layer,'new route\new shape.shp',False)
```

I haven't got any errors, it just does nothing. When I execute the code in the QGIS Text Editor, I click on "Run" and executes the file. Nothing appears on the map and I don't see any new shapefile in the folder written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to load manually the layer on the Map View of QGIS. For example, in my case of the next shapefile:

[image]

I ran your script (slightly modified to be tested on my system):

```
from qgis.analysis import QgsGeometryAnalyzer
lyr =iface.mapCanvas()
layer = lyr.currentLayer()
QgsGeometryAnalyzer().centroids(layer,'/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/centroid_pol2.shp', False)
```

and when I loaded the 'centroid_pol2' shapefile (at the specified path) it could be observed:

[image]

Comment: Hello xunilk, thank you for your answer. I have been watching this question too. 

My problem, as well, is that in the folder appears nothing. It is a system's folder, not external.  I refresh it and it doesn't have anything

Comment: The issue it is probably the 'path'. Above syntax is for a Linux system. Adapt for Windows if it is your case. For example: `C:/pyqgis_data/centroid_pol2.shp`

Comment: Yes, I have been trying in Windows, and set all the paths correctly. Well... this is amazing, I have been trying in "D:\..." disk, it didn't worked. And now, I have created a new folder in "C:\..." Finally it worked. 

Thank you very much. But now, I am confused, why does it work in one path but not in the other one?

Comment: The correct path is `D:/...` or `D:\\..`.

Comment: Can't attach an image, but well, I have been using "/" or "\\" for a long time, until I discovered that, in QGIS Essen, there isn't any problem (I load layers, typically using QgsVectorLayer, and QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsDataProvider...) writing "\".
'C:\folder\my_shp.shp'